# Cannot save settings in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

Whenever I make changes in the setting panel of Atom, it doesn't get saved. Everytime I close and re-open Atom, the changes are lost. This happens for the core settings, packages settings, everything.

edit : I'm running OSX 10.12(Sierra) with the latest version of Atom.

Anyone has a tip to prevent that ?

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using? How did you install Atom? Is your disk/filesystem working properly?

Comment: Sorry, I use osx 10.12 (Sierra), I've installed atom the traditional way (download the app and installed it on my system).My disk and filesystem are running properly. I have no other problem or bugs than this one.

Comment: I don’t use atom, but maybe it’s the same as sublime, which has “default” and “user” settings, and you can only update the “user” settings

Comment: @Alan I don't use Sublime, but I don't think it's that. The Settings panel in Atom only contains user-changeable settings. I don't think it even has "default" settings, though maybe they're in the config folder somewhere.

Comment: Restart computer?

Comment: Hmm, I looked for related questions on here but couldn't find any. This sounds like a bug. You could bring it up on the Atom [support forum](https://discuss.atom.io/c/support/8) or on the [issues page](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues).

Comment: I had the same problem and ended up deleting `~/.atom/config.cson` and some of the folders in that directory (except `packages`). Careful with that, you might want to backup those files/folders first.

Comment: @idleberg Thanks, I'll try that out !

Comment: Thanks, @idleberg! Nuking `~/.atom` worked!